# ignoring condition in where clause in mysql

Tags: mysql, jpa

Can we write conditional where clause in mysql?
I know one way i.e with CASE WHEN

But my condition is if where clause fails then ignore it and execute query as there was no where clause

eg.
I want to select persons in particular city. but if I got city null as input then ignore that statement and return all persons in all cities

Can someone please tell me how to do this

please Help!!

Comment: are you trying to write a sql or a jpql?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
select p from Person p where (:city is null or p.city = :city)
```

Comment: but this will give me where city is null in db(which can be possibility )

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. If you pass `null` for `:city` parameter, it will give you all Persons as result. If you pass any other value for `:city`, it will filter persons by that value. Can you explain more what will not work as expected?

Comment: Maybe this is your dilemma - if you pass `null` as param value, the first part of the condition will be true (`:city is null`) so, because of `or` the whole condition evaluates to true regardless of the second part (`p.city = :city`) so it won't be evaluated at all. In this case the whole query is equivalent to `select p from Person p where true`

Comment: this is amazing... I didnt think of this before...Its always like it evaluates to true and false and your query returns accordingly.. It worked and I understood login too... Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from your_table
where @city is null 
or city = @city
```

Comment: but this will give me where city is null

Comment: No, only if the variable is null. Distinguish between the column name `city` and the variable `@city`